# Связные списки без указателей и динамической памяти

Tags: c, массивы, list

Как на языке C без использования указателей и динамической памяти создать связный список, добавить в него элементы (в начало, в конец и после определённого элемента), распечатать его и удалить? Использовать можно только статические массивы с постоянными границами

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: как реализовать данную идею?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ну а что сложного? Список - это логическая структура, выражающая собой последовательность элементов. Массив - физическая структура, тоже выражающая последовательность элементов.
При реализации списка через динамическое выделение памяти у элемента есть указатель на следующий элемент. Если вы делаете список поверх массива - просто считаете что у элемента `arr[i]` указатель указывает на элемент `arr[i+1]`. Вот и вся концепция.
Исходя из реализации у вас только появляется одно ограничение - нельзя сделать список больше, чем размер массива.
Ну и начинаете заполнять список. Первый элемент списка попадает в `arr[0]`, следующий `arr[1]` и т.д. Заполнили `l` элементов.

- Чтобы добавить в конец списка, записываете элемент в `arr[l+1]` ячейку массива.
- Чтобы добавить в начало списка, копируете (сдвигаете) все элементы в массиве на 1 ячейку и в `arr[0]` записываете новый элемент.
- Чтобы вставить в середину, например пятый элемент - начиная с пятого элемента и до последнего сдвигаете элементы вправо, и в позицию `arr[5]` записываете новый элемент.

Чтобы немного слукавить, можно оставлять место в массиве не только в конце, но и в начале - чтобы можно было без копирований добавлять элементы и в конец и в начало списка. Примерно по такой концепции сделан `std::deque<>` . Но тогда нужно запоминать индексы и начала и конца списка. Например массив у вас на 100 элементов, а в списке всего 60. Тогда вы можете разместить список например с 10 по 70 ячейку массива.
Но при вставке в середину всё равно придется копировать.

Comment: Можно и более гибко (на той же идее, что ссылка на элемент списка, это индекс элемента массива). Сначала строим список свободных (заносим туда последовательно все элементы массива). Затем, при добавлении нового элемента списка, выбираем первый свободный и коррекирем индекс начала списка свободных, а в выбранный заносим данные и соответсвующим образом корректируем ссылки в нашем списке. Т.е. все почти так же, как при работе с обычными связными списками только вместо malloc/new берем новый элемент из списка свободных. Удаляемый из нашего списка элемент возвращаем в список свободных. Все

Comment: Согласен, можно и так. А можно и с указателями, только вместо выделения памяти динамически под каждый элемент класть этот элемент в массив. Т.е. в указателе `->next` использовать не индекс, а реальный адрес. Но это скорее относится к стратегии выделения памяти. Хотя в задании не понятно, чего именно хотели.